# Differentiating an integral with dependent limits

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

How would one reasonable differentiate the integral of the form $\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(x) dx$, provided $h$ is continuous? Does this even make reasonable sense? The main point is that the integrand is also a function of $x$.

Comment: This has been asked many times here, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule (see Example 2)

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(x) dx = \int_{0}^{g(x)} h(x) dx -\int_{0}^{f(x)} h(x) dx$$

Apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to get

$$ \frac {d}{dx} \int_{f(x)}^{g(x)} h(x) dx = h(g(x))g'(x) - h(f(x))f'(x) $$